# How to replace word with unique prefix and suffix?

Tags: sed

`testfile` starts with:

```
  abc: aprefixAnYthingasuffix
```

This sed operation is NOT working:

```
sed -i 's/aprefix*asuffix/mynewword/g' testfile
```

`testfile` ends with:

```
  abc: mynewword
```

http://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end

Comment: Try: `sed -i 's/aprefix.*asuffix/mynewword/g' testfile`.  `.*` means "zero or more of any character"; `x*` means "zero or more of `x`", which would match `aprefixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxasuffix`, for example.

Comment: that's it!  how can i learn more about this syntax and how it differs from regex?

Comment: "this syntax" **is** regex: it differs from shell globs (in particular, `*` means zero or more occurrences **of the previous regular expression**: your original version was only matching strings like `aprefixasuffix` and `aprefixxxxxxxasuffix`)

Comment: Specifically, `.` is the regex wildcard for "any one character", and `*` is regex-ese for "zero or more of that last thing", so `.*` is regex-ese for "any character followed by zero or more of any character(s)".

Comment: @DopeGhoti Why not make that an answer?

Comment: I can think of no reason not to, so I have. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `sed -i 's/aprefix.*asuffix/mynewword/g' testfile`. `.*` means "zero or more of any character"; `x*` means "zero or more of `x`", which would match `aprefixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxasuffix`, for example.

Specifically, `.` is the regex wildcard for "any one character", and `*` is regex-ese for "zero or more of that last thing", so `.*` is regex-ese for "any character followed by zero or more of any character(s)".